# Skipping Meditation After Great Exertion

Tags: meditation-practicalities

Yongey Mingyur Rinpoche, in a video, describes how some beginners exert themselves too much at once and then skip sessions. That is precisely my situation. Upon meditating for much longer than usual in one sitting, I skip subsequent days.

Yet, recently I found myself wishing to meditate more, but not doing so because I feared that phenomenon would happen again.

**How can this limitation (exertion then skipping) be overcome?**

Would for example taking longer breaks between short sessions (15 min of meditation) inhibit overexertion? What would be the ideal length of such a break?

Answer (score 3):

Meditation shouldn't be viewed as a need. You should neither regret that you skipped nor  wish that you do it.You are getting attached to the joy of meditation and this in itself is counterproductive to the practice.

Do it simply willingly any time you feel like it.Naturally then a rhythm will form that suites your lifestyle.

And remember that the practice should be applied in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

Use mindfulness. Keep a record of which days you meditate, and for how long. Find ways to graph your progress. There are apps for smart phones that do this, but a simple "Practice Journal" with notes is better, as you can add whatever you want to it. It's impossible to hold everything in your memory, so notes allow you to look back and review your experience, set goals, and work towards them.

Answer (score 1):

You keep using this meaningless word that is mediation, as if it is a good idea... whereas nobody knows what you mean by that.

if you mean bhavana, then say bhavana and the answer to your question is obvious. Bhavana means you do it as much as you can, each day, all the time.
If you want to be more specific, then you use jhana, sati sampajanna or the other 2 Samādhibhāvanās https://www.buddha-vacana.org/sutta/anguttara/04/an04-041.html

Sati sampajanna is obvious, since you do that as long as there is  vitakka, vedana and sanna, so again pretty much all the time, certainly not 15 minutes a day, and then spending 23h45min not developing thoughts renunciation, non-ill will and harmlessness.
you will never clean the mind by spending 23h45min each day not developing renunciation, non-ill will and harmlessness, by not forcing seeing things as anicca, dukkha anatta.
Development means exactly the opposite of whatever you are doing in 15 minutes per day, which is certainly not training the mind.
Even the people who train and clean the body do not claim they train and clean the body by spending 15minutes per day on the body, and the mind is even harder to train and clean...

Jhana is when you want sukha and you cannot do that all the time, you can pause for a few hours up to a few days, especially when you are not a idle bikkhu.

The last 2 Samādhibhāvanās are done when you want to acquire knowledge of karma and nibanna, so it is not relevant for you here.